# javascript what is t exactly, because i dont know

Tags: javascript

I need understand this part of code:

```
function spin(t) {

  var e = t.roll;
  play_sound('roll');

  for (var a = [1, 14, 2, 13, 3, 12, 4, 0, 11, 5, 10, 6, 9, 7, 8], n = 0, i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {  
      if (e == a[i]) {        
          n = i;
          break;          
      }      
  }
  var s = 32;
  var o =- 32;
  var l = Math.floor(t.wobble * (s - o + 1) + o);
  var c = 70 * n + 36 + l;

  c += 5250;
  animStart = (new Date).getTime();

  vi = getVi(c);
  tf = getTf(vi);

  isMoving = true;
  setTimeout(function() {  
      finishRoll(t, tf);      
  }, tf);

  render();
}
```

In this part:

```
var l = Math.floor(t.wobble * (s - o + 1) + o);
```

I dont know what is the number or formula for the var `t`

The all code is this:

https://pastebin.com/3LtDftVV

Comment: t is passed in to the function (`function spin(t)`), so you'll need to look and see how it's called to find the definition of t.

Comment: Looks like there is an ajax call. `.ajax({'url': "/scripts/getToken.php?v=" + (new Date()).getTime(), success: function(data) {`. The response has some data and that eventually gets passed to spin.

Answer (score 0):

`t` is the input parameter of the `spin` function.
So in order to understand what `t` is, you have to check where `spin` is called.

It is called inside the function `__SOCKET_EVENT_ROLL(data)`, passing that `data` as parameter. 
So now in order to understand what `t` is, you need to understand what `data` in when calling that function `__SOCKET_EVENT_ROLL`.

That function is bound to the `SOCKET.on roll` event. And the data is the data passed from the event.

So, your `t` is the data passed in the hook `SOCKET.on roll`

Comment: Thanks bro. Is posible to know the number of the data? To can use with the formula.

Comment: What do you mean with the "number of the data"?